# UPDATE involving three tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have three tables involved in this query I need to create, and I'm not exactly sure how to join these two (**address** & **address_key**)  tables in order to update the **office** table.

I have an **office** table, an **address** table, and an **address_key** table. 
The **office** table has address data (street,city,state,zip) and an office ID#.

The **address** table has address data and an address Id#.

The **address_key** table has address_id's and office_id's.  I need to update existing rows in the **office** table with address data from the **address** table linking them with keys from the **address_key** table.

How would I go about updating the **office** table address data fields?

Comment: This looks like homework. It is really expected on this site that for homework questions the OP (Original Poster, you) exhibit effort before any assistance is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the address_key table and for each row, update the office record with office_id with the address info using the address_id in each row you're looping through. I think something like this should work if you're using oracle (the question was tagged with oracle11g):

```
FOR id_row in (SELECT * FROM address_key)
LOOP
    UPDATE office SET (street, city, state, zip) = 
        (SELECT street, city, state, zip FROM address WHERE address_id = id_row.address_id);
    WHERE office_id = id_row.office_id
END LOOP
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Helped Very much.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
update o set
    street = a.street
    , city = a.city
    , state = a.state
    , zip = a.zip
from Office o
join Address_Key k
    on k.officeid = o.officeID
join Address a
    on a.addressID = k.addressid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run an UPDATE based on your joins.

```
UPDATE office
SET office.street = address.street ,
 office.city = address.city ,
 office.state = address. ,
 office.zip = address.zip 
FROM office
 INNER JOIN address_key ON office.office_id = address_key.office_id
 INNER JOIN address ON address_key.address_id = address.address_id
```